# How do i store data in text file in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

[
{
"name": "Game of thorn", "min_players": 3, "max_players": 4,
"duration": 90,
"min_age": 10 },
{
"name": "Mortal Galaxy", "min_players": 2, "max_players": 4,
"duration": 45,
"min_age": 12
}
Th]

Comment: what did you try and what where the results.   this is a site to help you with the code you wrote,  not one to help you write it.

Answer (score 0):

```
sample_dict = { "name": "Game of thorn", "min_players": 3, "max_players": 4, "duration": 90, "min_age": 10 }, { "name": "Mortal Galaxy", "min_players": 2, "max_players": 4, "duration": 45, "min_age": 12 } 

import json

with open('file.txt', 'w') as file:
     file.write(json.dumps(sample_dict))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).